# Android Honeycomb - Tab

Tags: android

Previously I wanted to use Tabs on top of the page using TabActivity.

As I am working with Honeycomb I used Action Bar Tabs. That worked best for me.

Now, I want to use tab to on Login page, so that user can Log in two diff ways. For this, I thought I will put Tabs at the top of Login layout (center of the page and not top of the page).

Can I do that ? How?

Comment: This question is way to general. What have you tried so far? What isn't working? We need specifics.

Comment: I have tried Action bar tabs. I would like have same thing inside the page not at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a tabhost with multiple views and even multiple activities in each tab.

Here is a tutorial : http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=59

The tab host doesn't have to occupy the whole screen you can have something else on top, I sometime put a textview with the title.